# Using php variable in querySelector

Tags: javascript, php

This may be basic, but I have searched half the day for an answer that works. I have a form that is dynamically created in a while statement (returns many forms). I am using jQuery to get the form name and I needed a unique name for each form, otherwise it just works on the first one.

I created a dynamic form name with a number concatenated to the end for each iteration and that is working fine resulting in a unique form name for each form. Now I want to use the variable in the querySelector - It wants a string though. How can I pass the variable as a string in each loop? If it is in quotes it uses the typed in string and if I use the variable it breaks it.

```
var form_name = <?php echo '#'.$form_name; ?>;
document.querySelector(**form_name**).addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
var form = this;
more code…
```

This is full code (most of it)

```
                $watch_num = 0;
                while ($row_watched = mysqli_fetch_row($result_watched))
                {
                    $watch_num = $watch_num + 1;
                    $delete_name = "delete_form".$watch_num;

                    echo '<table width="570" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4"'.$background.'>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="148" rowspan="5" align="center" valign="top"><img src="'.$image.'" vspace="4" hspace="6" width="140" height="105" style="padding-top:3px" /></td>
                        <td>Item Number:'.$number.'</td><td align="right">'.$featured.'</td>
                        </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><strong>Title: '.$title.'</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td width="222">Trader: '.$lister.'</td>
                        <td width="176">'.$type.'</td>
                        </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>'.$time_status.'</td>
                        <td>'.$price.'</td>
                        </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>';
                        if($status == "A" || $status == "X" || $status == "C"){
                        echo '<input name="other" type="button" class="grn_button_small2" id="other" value="More From Seller" onclick="window.location=\'seller.php?sellerid='.$lister.'\'"  />';
                        }

                        if($status == "A"){
                        echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="details" type="button" class="grn_button_small2" id="details" value="Details" onclick="window.location=\'details.php?itemid='.$item_id.'\'"  /></td>';
                        }
                        echo '<td><form name="'.$delete_name.'" method="post" action="" id="delete_form">
                            <input type="hidden" id="item" name="item" value="'.$item_id.'" />
                            <input type="submit" class="grn_button_small2" id="delete_btn" name="delete_btn" value="Stop Watching"/>  
                            </form>';
                            echo '</td>
                        </tr>
    ?>
<script>

     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var form_name = <?php echo json_encode("#$delete_name"); ?>; 
document.querySelector(form_name).addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  var form = this;
      var stop_abort = "\nYou didnt stop it";

      e.preventDefault();
      swal({
          title: "Stop",
          text: "Are you sure you want to stop?",
          closeOnClickOutside: false,
          dangerMode: true,
          buttons: [
            'Cancel',
            'Stop'
          ],
        }).then(function(isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm) {
        swal({
          title: 'Cancelled!',
          text: 'Stopped',
          //icon: 'success'
        }).then(function() {
          form.submit(); // <--- submit form programmatically
        });
      } else {
            swal("Stop  Aborted!", stop_abort);
          }
        });
    });
});
</script>
                <?php
                      </table><hr align="center" color="#D4D8E1" noshade="noshade" />';
         }//end while
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this:

```
<form name="'.$delete_name.'" method="post" action="" id="delete_form">
```

where you should have this:

```
<form name="'.$delete_name.'" method="post" action="" id="'.$delete_name.'">
```

or even this:

```
<form id="'.$delete_name.'" method="post"> <!-- No need for name, nor action -->
```

for two reasons:

- you can't have several HTML elements with the same ID,
- when you use `document.querySelector` with `#something`, it refers to the ID, not the name.

For the rest, see @miken32's answer.

As a general note though, generating IDs like this is bad practice and not needed 99% of the time. You could just give all your forms a specific class, or better yet, a specific `data-` attribute, and then query them all at once with jQuery or `document.querySelectorAll(...).addEventListener` (you seem to mix both syntaxes, btw).

Comment: Thought it was calling the element by name, not ID but this works perfectly. Thanks, you guys are lifesavers! Up vote but it won't show because I am a new guy.

Comment: @user2770444 You're welcome. If you can, mark the answer as accepted. Thanks and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're quoting your value. An easy way to do this is with `json_encode` which can take care of escaping any values that need escaping.

```
var form_name = <?=json_encode("#$form_name")?>;
document.querySelector(form_name).addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    var form = this;
    //...
});
```

Comment: This isn't working either. When I changed the code it returns an empty variable. Here is the code view before I changed …
var form_name = #watch_delete_form1;
    document.querySelector(form_name).addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      var form = this;
But after the change it was 
 var form_name  =  ;

Comment: Then you’re doing something wrong. There’s not much more basic than echoing a value onto a page. You’d at least get the #.

Comment: I know, which is why it is so frustrating

Comment: @user2770444 Please show your code after you updated it (according to this answer). It shouldn't be possible for that to output `var form_name = ;`. The `#` should be there at least.

Comment: Tweaked the var name and it shows in the view source correctly now, but isn't passed to the querySelector. From the page view source: var form_name = "#watch_delete_form1";
    document.querySelector(form_name).addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      var form = this;

Comment: It is passed to querySelector, you just pasted code into your comment that shows it is.

Comment: the new code... var form_name = <?php echo json_encode("#$watch_delete_name"); ?>;
    document.querySelector(form_name).addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      var form = this;

Comment: Yes. You’re giving a value to a variable called `form_name` and then using it in a function on the next line. It’s not going to disappear between those two lines.

Comment: the querySelector expects a string, not a variable, so the value isn't getting passed. If I code the form name right in it works. This is working for only the first returned row though and I need it to work each time, hence the dynamic names.     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    document.querySelector('#delete_form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      var form = this;

Comment: edited the question to include most of the code (edited the code a little too)